# How do you reuse a texture in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

In blender internal render, in material nodes, there is a "texture" node by which you can select a previously created texture. But in cycles there is no such node for material nodes, all the nodes are to create new texture. How do you apply an already created texture?

Comment: What kind of nodes in Cycles do you mean? Material? Compositing? There is Image Texture node in material nodes and both Image and Texture nodes in compositing nodes. [Edit] your question with more information please

Comment: @MrZak i have edited the question, can you help please?

Comment: You can create arbitrary groups on nodes including any textures and reuse them in any other material from the *Groups* menu

Comment: You can just copy Image Texture node with Shift+D and put it where desired.. Or you can choose image to be reused in the dropdown of the image Texture node after adding new Image Texture node. That should be pretty basic operations. Or create group of nodes by Ctrl+G and reuse it.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thank you, this is a good solution

Comment: @MrZak thank you, but duplicating is not reusing. It is just quick creating a new node so you don't have to reenter all the values manually. Groups seems like a way to go :)

Comment: As i understand, there are no textures in cycles, only materials. And all the texture options are just part of material settings.

Comment: Duplicating in this case is reusing - you reuse the same image texture datablock. Groups essentially will do just the same but with more visual layout convenience. There are textures in Cycles, they are added to materials via Image Texture node

Answer (score -1):

You can choose it here, at the Material tab.
The same option you can find at the bottom of the Node Editor.

[image]

Comment: These are materials available in the file, not textures. It is not clear what textures does OP ask as well